# Equivalent Condition for Being a Division Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with at least two elements and suppose that for any non-zero $a\in R$ there exists a unique $b\in R$ such that $aba = a$. Prove that $R$ is a division ring.

Given the assumptions and $a\in R$ we have $aba = a$, then $aba - a = 0 = a(ba - 1) = (ab-1)a$. If $ab-1$ and $ba-1$ are both not zero divisors, then $ab - 1 = 0$ and $ba - 1 = 0$ so that $ab = ba = 1$ and $b = a^{-1}$. I'm not sure what to do in the case when there are zero divisors. I've seen that in general, division rings don't have zero divisors, but I don't know a priori that $R$ is a division ring (as that's what I'm trying to prove haha).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have observed, it suffices to show that $R$ has no (nonzero) zero divisors.  To prove this, you will have to use the *uniqueness* hypothesis you haven't used yet.  If $a\in R$ is a zero divisor, try and show that the $b$ such that $aba=a$ cannot be unique.

The details of how to do this are hidden below.

> Suppose $a\neq 0$ is a left zero divisor, so there is some nonzero $c$ such that $ac=0$ (the case of a right zero divisor is similar, and in fact unnecessary because $R$ has left zero divisors iff it has right zero divisors).  By hypothesis, there exists some $b$ such that $aba=a$.  But then $a(b+c)a=aba+aca=aba=a$ as well.  Since $b\neq b+c$, this shows that this $b$ is not unique, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Sweet! That's just the missing piece! Thanks! :)

(And the Algebra qual studying continues haha...)

Comment: Also, how did you do the hiding bit?

Comment: Start a line with >! and it will be hidden.

Comment: Pardon me if i am wrong but i have a doubt.We need to prove that ring is without zero divisors .  To prove that , you have started with specific $a $ being zero divisor and shown that it is not , to which agreed. But how does it prove in general that ring has no zero divisors ?

Comment: @llecxe: $a$ is an arbitrary element of $R$.

Comment: Thanks , you are right